# XmlSerializer and xsi: deserialization

Tags: c#, wcf, xmlserializer

I'm having a hard time trying to deserialize this chunk of XML code corresponding to a WCF SOAP service FAULT detail section because of the xsi:type="p:OUTPUT-HEADER" attribute:

```
<p:OUTPUT-HEADER xsi:type="p:OUTPUT-HEADER" xmlns:p="http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2" xmlns:ns0="http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FAULT>
    <p:COD-ERROR>2951</p:COD-ERROR>
    <p:COD-SEV>8</p:COD-SEV>
    <p:MSG-ERROR>Error message</p:MSG-ERROR>
  </FAULT>
  <CNL-OUT>xxx</CNL-OUT>
</p:OUTPUT-HEADER>
```

These are the classes I'm using:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(OutputHeader))]
public abstract class FaultDetail
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FAULT", Namespace = "")]
    public Fault FaultSection{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CNL-OUT", Namespace = "")]
    public string ClnOut{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OUTPUT-HEADER", Namespace = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2")]
public class OutputHeader : FaultDetail
{
}

public class Fault
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "COD-ERROR")]
    public int CodigoError { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "COD-SEV")]
    public int Severidad { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MSG-ERROR")]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }

}
```

The XmlSerializer:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OutputHeader));
```

And the error I'm getting when calling the deserialize method:

"The specified type was not recognized: name 
='OUTPUT-HEADER', namespace='http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2', at <OUTPUT-HEADER 
xmlns='http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2'>."

Is it possible to decorate the classes to deserialize this XML correctly?
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: WCF serializes and deserializes content sent across the wire automatically.  Is there a specific reason you want to do it manually?

Comment: I understand the 'auto' way should be to use FaultException.GetDetail<OutputHeader>, but no OutputHeader class  has been generated  as the wsdl doesn't contain any info related to it. So my next move is to get the FaultException.GetReaderAtDetailContents() stream and try to deserialize it. Or am I missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `XmlSerializer`, it seems you must use [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) to deserialize this XML.  This serializer is the [default serializer for WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx) so you would simply need to remove the code where you specify use of `XmlSerializer`.

Design your types as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public abstract class OutputHeaderBase
{
    [DataMember(Name = "FAULT", Order = 1)]
    public Fault FaultSection { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CNL-OUT", Order = 2)]
    public string ClnOut { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "OUTPUT-HEADER", Namespace = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2")]
public class OutputHeader : OutputHeaderBase
{
}

[DataContract(Name = "FAULT", Namespace = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2")]
public class Fault
{
    [DataMember(Name = "COD-ERROR", Order = 1)]
    public int CodigoError { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "COD-SEV", Order = 2)]
    public int Severidad { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "MSG-ERROR", Order = 3)]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
}
```

Then declare your operation contract as returning (or accepting) an object of type `OutputHeader` (**not `OutputHeaderBase`**).

Finally switch back to data contract serialization by removing [`[XmlSerializerFormat]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) from your service and/or operation contract, and you should be all set.  For details of switching see [Using the XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx)

(Note also the properties of `Fault` need to be placed into the correct namespace.)

**Why does this work**?

The [`"xsi:type"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) attribute is a w3c standard attribute that allows an element to explicitly assert its type.  Both [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx) and [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759.aspx) use this attribute to convey actual type information when serializing a polymorphic type.  However, the following element:

```
<p:OUTPUT-HEADER 
    xsi:type="p:OUTPUT-HEADER" 
    xmlns:p="http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
</p:OUTPUT-HEADER>
```

Has base type `OUTPUT-HEADER` in namespace `http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2` and subtype `OUTPUT-HEADER` in namespace `http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2` -- i.e. the type and subtype information are identical and so the `xsi:type` attribute is redundant.

But, if it's redundant, it should be harmless, right?  You could design a type hierarchy for `XmlSerializer` as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OUTPUT-HEADER", Namespace = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(OutputHeaderSubclass))] // Artificial subtype to trigger handling of the `xsi:type` attribute.
[XmlInclude(typeof(OutputHeader))]
public class OutputHeader
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FAULT", Namespace = "")]
    public Fault FaultSection { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CNL-OUT", Namespace = "")]
    public string ClnOut { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OUTPUT-HEADER-SUBCLASS", Namespace = "http://aaa.bbb.ccc/v2")]
public class OutputHeaderSubclass : OutputHeader
{
}
```

Then deserializing to `OutputHeader` might well work.  Unfortunately, it doesn't. `XmlSerializer` throws an exception for the redundant attribute rather than handling it.  Conversely `DataContractSerializer` does not, so that's the one to use.

Comment: Impressive, very well explained and documented answer. I was using XmlSerializer as I thought DataContractSerializar could't handle the different namespaces in the hierachy, but I see now I was misunderstanding the XML.  Thanks very much dbc!